# Turn CSS animation into javascript

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, transform

I would like to convert the following CSS animation into a JavaScript animation so that it functions on click of a `div` called "button".

```css
#book1:hover>.hardcover_front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-145deg) translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-145deg) translateZ(0);
  transform: rotateY(-145deg) translateZ(0);
  z-index: 0;
}
```

I understand how to do the transformations in Javascript, just wondering how to do the trigger, so for the button on click to affect the `.hardcover_front` of `#book1`

Comment: Add the animation to a class then add the class to the element when the button is clicked

Comment: @Ihazkode kindly put that in an answer so that I can upvote you!

Comment: No need. You will probably get more detailed answers from others in a few moments. If not you can write up an answer using this method and then accept it.

Comment: @Ihazkode how do I make it so that the class only gets added to the child of `#book1` using javascript?

Comment: `document.querySelector('#book1 > .hardcover_front').classList.add('animation_class')`